# Why does my bash pattern match not work properly when 'piped' through nodejs exec?

Tags: node.js, bash, gruntjs, grunt-shell

I am running following command on git bash (windows)

```
paste --delimiter=\\n --serial src/libs/**/*[^.spec].js > test.js
```

with shopt:

```
globstar on
extglob on
```

This successfully concats all js files recursively from src/libs on, except all *.spec.js files when executed from terminal.

However, when I run this command through grunt-shell (https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) it works also but : [^.spec] is ignored. Means all my *.spec.js files get into test.js too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With extglob (and globstar) the following syntax is correct the other `[^`..`]` is a negative character set.

```
paste --delimiter=\\n --serial src/libs/**/!(*.spec).js > test.js
```

Otherwise it can be done with find

```
find src/libs -name '*.js' ! -name '*.spec.js' -exec paste --delimiter='\n' --serial {} + > test.js
```

Is there any difference with

```
find src/libs ! -name '*.spec.js' -name '*.js' -exec cat {} + > test.js
```

Comment: there's a subtile dfference when last line of file doesn't have a end-of-line character `cat` doesn't add whereas `paste` does

Comment: ah yeah right, tried the second (it is safer, since this is part of a build routine) -- escaping--delimiter='\n' to --delimiter='\\n' worked for me..